# Is there a way to minimize the finite size effects in VASP calculations?

Tags: vasp

I am trying to find the interaction potential profile of electrolyte and a slab system(particularly one type of oxygen atom). I started with two slab systems, one with 200 odd atoms and the other with 520 odd atoms. So far I have been getting big deviations in the energy profiles. My guessing is that this could be a finite size effect and is there a way to check this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method is making a bigger slab system and check results again. The finite size is hard to solve in pbc condition. We can only get a more converged results.

Comment: Thank you for the response